# Help dealing with .htaccess for making my URL pretty

Tags: php, apache

My current URL look like this.

> http://example.com/news.php?id=25&cat=news&date=01092010&title=this-is-the-first-title

i want to make it cleaner like

> http://example.com/news/01092010/this-is-the-first-title

i just know the basic of how .htaccess works with the basic understanding of its directive, how do i achieve this?

Edit : i dont want the id to be displayed.

thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pretty+url Why not to put just a small effort to help yourself?

Comment: `/news/01092010/this-is-the-first-title` can easily be converted but you must manually look up the `id` (if necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z-]+)$ /news.php?cat=$1&date=$2&title=$3
```

But note the `id` is not contained in this "pretty URL"! Therefore, you must manually look this up (or you directly fetch the news item) in news.php based on the values from `$_GET['date']` and `$_GET['title']`.

The rule above will convert a request on the form `http://example.com/news/01092010/this-is-the-first-title` into `http://example.com/news.php?cat=news&date=01092010&title=this-is-the-first-title`.

Comment: i dont want the id to be displayed. how do i do it?

Comment: What you *could* do is add it to the "pretty URL", e.g. `http://example.com/news/01092010/25-this-is-the-first-title` and then match it (`^([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)-([a-z-]+)$`). Alternatively you must do a look-up.

Comment: @Ibrahim, then you will need to lookup title/date from the database and get the matching record, which should be the requested article.

Comment: @Ibrahim Azhar Armar Ah, then you *must* do a look-up, cf. @aularon's comment.