# PHP script to make page as a folder structure

Tags: php, .htaccess, query-string, directory

I have a website with different pages but the query string looks ugly, how can I make it look like a folder structure instead of a query string, instead of actually having folders in my www?

Comment: wow.. you're gonna have to elaborate a bit.. What do you mean by query string?

Comment: You're looking for some rewrite rules to turn something like this: "foo.php?bar=baz" into "/foo/bar/baz"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help dealing with .htaccess for making my URL pretty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625877/help-dealing-with-htaccess-for-making-my-url-pretty)

Comment: many many many many other dupes as well: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pretty+url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try out this free online tool : http://www.webconfs.com/url-rewriting-tool.php just type in your dynamic ( ugly ) url and copy the generated Directory-type htaccess code and paste it in the .htaccess file ( if it doesn't exist, create one ) in your root directory. Ensure that mod_rewrite is active in your php.ini configuration file. To know more about it, you can google the term.

Answer (score 1):

After reading your question a few times, I think you're referring to routing.

If you're using apache, you can look at

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

You can look at this tutorial for php:

http://www.phpaddiction.com/tags/axial/url-routing-with-php-part-one/

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable mod-rewrite and define rewrite rules in .htaccess page.

here is some useful document.

http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use routing in your application, I'd suggest having a look at Symfony's [Routing](https://github.com/symfony/Routing) component, which you can use standalone.